# Deleting key from expanding multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array that keeps expanding when I add values to it, and I'm trying to write a function to remove a specific value from a key,

This is what the array looks like currently

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [CanViewAdminCP] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [Type] => System
                                            [Description] => Grants user access to admin backend
                                            [Colour] => blue
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [CanViewModCP] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Type] => System
                                    [Description] => Grants user access to moderator backend
                                    [Colour] => blue
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CanUseSkript] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Type] => System
                            [Description] => Grants user access to Skript Functions
                            [Colour] => blue
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And this is my function that i tried however it seems to remove everything and return the array?

```
function DeleteKey($array, $key) {
    if( isset($array[$key]) ) {
        unset($array[$key]);
        return $array;
    } else {
        foreach($array as $elem) {
            if(is_array($elem))
            $return = DeleteKey($elem, $key);
            if(!is_null($return)) break;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: what would be your resultant array and which key you want to remove?

Comment: @Rahulsm  lets say i wanted to remove the key 'CanViewModCP' i put that as a key into my function and it returns nothing, it removes everything from the array

Comment: Check why the array keep expanding is the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to unset your value array by index,

```
function custom_unset(&$arr, $key) {
    unset($arr[$key]);
    foreach ($arr as &$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            custom_unset($v, $key);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
$temp = custom_unset($arr,"CanViewModCP");
print_r($temp);
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ca552ce5f39fc3a204b04743613737dac2c2f4a).

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you notice you're adding behaviour to a structure of arrays, it can be beneficial to consider refactoring the structure into a set of dedicated classes. This will allow better, fine-grained control over the operations.

Since you're using an array structure, and considering the nature of your question, a simple solution would be to just use a plain old `unset`.
For instance, with your sample data, you could remove the moderator backend access using:

```
unset($array[0][0][1]);
```

The reason why your function is not working as expected, is because it immediately returns the child-array instead of a whole copy with an element removed.

Lets walk through the steps. Consider the following array:

```
$array = [
    ['a' => 'hello', 'b' => 'Hello'],
    ['a' => 'world', 'b' => 'World'],
];
```

Now let's say we want to delete the key 'a'.
When invoking DeleteKey, first it checks if $array['a'] is set.
Since $array has only key 0 and 1, that results in false.
Now we loop through $array. The first thing we find is:

```
['a' => 'hello', 'b' => 'Hello']
```

On that input, DeleteKey get invoked again.
This time, the key 'a' is found. It is removed, and ['b' => 'Hello'] is returned.
Since ['b' => 'Hello'] does not equal null, the loop breaks here.
['b' => 'Hello'] is returned.

By reading the function, it's not entirely clear what the original intention was. 
For example, we could interpret it as: "Remove all entries that have this key in all of the arrays contained in this array", in which case the function could look like this:

```
function deleteKey($array, $key) {
    if( isset($array[$key]) ) {
        unset($array[$key]);
        return $array;
    }
    foreach($array as $k => $value) {
        $return[$k] = $value;
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $return[$k] = DeleteKey($value, $key);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

But it could be that you only want the first one to be removed, or only the last? Who knows!